# Is there a nodejs module for converting epub books to pdf?

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, telegram, epub

I am trying to create a telegram bot (in nodejs) for converting epub files to pdf but I can't find any npm module for doing that.

Does anyone know of any module that can receive an epub file and return a pdf file?

Comment: Asking for libs is off-topic on SO. I'd expect that there's none and you need some cross-platform binaries.

Comment: Alright. Then where would be the right place to ask such question if not SO?

Comment: Quora, Reddit or some dev forums. I don't see why installing calibre or other linux binaries is a problem. You will likely need them any way, proceed from this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's one https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebook-convert. But to use it you need to install calibre on your pc https://calibre-ebook.com/download. After you've installed both of them you can convert epub to pdf using code like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

const convert = require('ebook-convert');
const options = {
  input: appDir + '/public/123.epub', //path to epub
  output: appDir + '/public/456.pdf', //path to pdf
};
convert(options, function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I would need to run the bot on a public server (like heroku) and installing calibre-ebook wouldn't be possible.